# Updating to Microsoft Access Object library 12.0, from DAO 3.6

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have some vb.net software using DAO 3.6, I am looking to upgrade it to use the MS access 12 library so I can run the software on windows 7 64bit.

Firstly am I correct in thinking that this library works with windows 7 64-bit and Access 2007?

My current Code:

```
Imports dao
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports system.data


Public Sub DAOAccess()

    Dim dbe As dao.DBEngine
    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    dbe = New DBEngine

    Dim x, y As Integer

    ConnectionString = "J:\home\THC2WO\FieldMaster\DAO\FieldMaster.mdb"
    db = dbe.OpenDatabase(ConnectionString)
    rs = db.OpenRecordset("tabParameters")
    rs.Index = "ID_PAR"
    rs.MoveFirst()

    'frmFieldMaster.TextBox21.Text = ""
    For x = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
        For y = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            frmFieldMaster.TextBox21.Text = frmFieldMaster.TextBox21.Text & rs.Fields(y).Value & ", "
        Next
        rs.MoveNext()
        frmFieldMaster.TextBox21.Text = frmFieldMaster.TextBox21.Text & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    Next

    rs.Close()
    db.Close()
```

I am struggling to find which imports I need at the start of the module to enable the new DBEngine. Also are there any big syntax changes when updating the reference?

If someone has some sample code including references that would help greatly.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do consider migrating to ADO.Net instead.

If you do decide to migrate to ADO, you could look at some of the old advice for migrating from DAO to ADO in VB6. A lot of this advice will still be very relevant, as it relates to object models, differences in the database providers, etc. Here are some links

- http://blackbeltvb.com/index.htm?daotoado.htm
- Useful Microsoft article that has been deleted from MSDN and AFAIK is now only available on third-party sites. *Thanks, Microsoft!* [Start here at the beginning](http://www.labath.org/docs/sys/mssql2000/mdacxml/htm/migratingdaotoado.htm), or dive straight into the topic on [opening a recordset](http://www.labath.org/docs/sys/mssql2000/mdacxml/htm/wpmigratingretrieving.htm)
- Microsoft [KB INFO: Issues Migrating from DAO/Jet to ADO/Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225048)

Comment: Looking at these links they seem to refer to quite old references and Access 2000. Can you please confirm for me that these references etc work correctly on Windows 7 and with Access 2007?

Comment: @Pezzzz I think it's the best information available. The ADO object model hasn't been changed for a number of years. The migration you are proposing is from a *very old* technology (DAO) to an *old* technology (ADO). Therefore the best advice available is the advice published when ADO came out, and everyone migrated from DAO to ADO. However, do consider migrating to a *new* technology instead (ADO.Net).

Comment: ok I miss-understood your answer, I thought the links were relating to migrating to ADO.net. Do you know of any links for ADO.net?

Comment: @Pezzzz There won't be any links specifically for migrating **DAO** to **ADO.Net** unfortunately. There's lots of ADO.Net documentation out there, though.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a reference to the COM object Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library. Then you should be able to import Interop Access.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
```

However, I really recommend you consider moving to ADO.NET instead. It is quite different from DAO or ADO (classic) but it is also much more robust and flexible.

Comment: is ado.net considered faster than dao, as speed is my main requirement, also can you supply some sample code/a  guide for ado.net